# Finger Paint path gets huge over time and slows the app

Tags: java, design, android

So I am writing a Finger paint app. I have multiple color which user can select. I save the path and paint information inside an array.

```
  ArrayList<PaintPath> arrayPaintPath = new ArrayList<PaintPath>();
```

Paint path is

```
class PaintPath{
    Paint aPaint;
    Path  aPath;
    PaintPath(Paint paint, Path path){
        aPaint = paint;
        aPath   = path;
    }
}
```

and inside the onTouch I collect for every action.

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

    float x = event.getX();
    float y = event.getY();

    switch(event.getAction()){
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        mypath  = new Path();
        mypaint = new Paint();
        mypaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mypaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        mypaint.setStrokeWidth(8f);
        mypath.moveTo(x, y);
        break;

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        mypath.lineTo(x, y);
        break;

    default:
        return true;
    }

    // see which color was selected by user
    setColor(mypaint); 

    // see if eraser was selected
    if(Palette.currentPaletteState == Palette.PaletteState.ERASER){
        mypaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));
        mypaint.setStrokeWidth(50f); 
    }

    // Here is were the array gets populated and the onDraw method 
    // use this array to draw
    arrayPaintPath.add(new PaintPath(mypaint,mypath));

    // force to call onDraw method
    invalidate();
    return true;  // return true to keep the event to this child only
}
```

Then onDraw method

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

    for(PaintPath p: arrayPaintPath){

        mycanvas.drawPath(p.aPath, p.aPaint);

        canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, 0, 0,null);

    }
}
```

So the main problem is with the forloop. As the user paint over time the path and paint gets collected, as well as eraser's path also get collected. The array gets larger and larger. This significantly reduces the performance.

I know that I could use SurfaceView and handle the work in another thread, but that thread also eventually ends up doing looping over the huge array.

Does anyone know what would be an elegant solution to this?

Comment: Are you trimming repetitive and very near points?  So rather than storing every point, you'd store only new points that were further than X units away from the last.  Depending on the sensitivity of the device, that may dramatically cut down on the number of points you are saving.

Comment: imo, the question of "how to improve performance when tracking many points" is completely on topic here.

Comment: @GrandmasterB While trimming repetitive points shouldn't I check if that particular point is in the array? Wouldn't it be a problem since I try to check a single element from the entire array? Or I guess I could change my data structure from array to hash map ...

Comment: Can't you cache the most recent combined bit map and apply new painting paths over that?  You'd only have to redraw the whole thing for an erase event (or resize or zoom).

Comment: Is there a functional requirement that you keep every paint event and erase event back to the beginning of time?

Comment: @ErikEidt I think I could do so .. good point .. I will look into it and let you know

Comment: Even erase events might be taken as paint events of background color?  Depends on semantics of erase, if it is more a delete of a segment or a draw, I guess.

Comment: @SailsMan63 not necessarily I guess Erik's point and ur point converges

Comment: @ErikEidt Its is more of a delete of draw .. yes

Comment: @pokche no, just compare them to the last point you added to the array.  Duplicate points would be fine if paths crossed.  Its repetitive points you want to remove.

Comment: @GrandmasterB yup that made a lot of difference ... I will also implement Erik's plan .. will let post answer latter

Answer (score 2):

The issue appears to be that you are redoing a massive amount of work as the user continues drawing over time. If you have already drawn the first 1000 steps, you should not have to draw them all again in order to get to the 1001st.

To resolve, refactor this so that your app stores the last position drawn. And so that your draw method continues drawing only from the last position. You will need the ability to call a full redraw of course. But that is easily handled with an input parameter to (or other flag accessible by) your draw method.

Regarding the clean up of the array as discussed in comments: I would keep that on the "maybe" list just in case. But it seems unlikely to be time-effective. After refactoring the drawing algorithm, obsolete drawing steps will only impact the rare cases where a full redraw is needed. And even then, may be minimally noticeable.

Good luck!